# C# Webservice Proxy Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, web, service

I have a c# application which consumes a webservice through a client proxy. The webservice is setup to use windows authentication (HTTP 401 challange through Active Directory). My user account configured to be authorized to access the webservice.

When I call the webservice through the browser it worked well. The browser is able to do the 401 challange and does not ask for any user id password (as internally the server and client do it through AD controller).

The problem is that when I try to consume the service through the C# application, it throws HTTP request unauthorized error.

I have tried all the below options for the webservice proxy to do windows authentication.

```
ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation
ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials as System.Net.NetworkCredential
ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation
```

Can someone please help on how I can make the webservice call just like how the browser does. I cannot pass user id and password while calling the service.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself a workaround.The service call works well (HTTP 401 challange) with HTTPWebRequest with Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. Browser seems to be using the same approach.The problem is while creating a client proxy which is unable to do this 401 challange.

I could not figureout the reason but may be the service does not have enough meta information to establish a proper handshake with a client proxy.